# Setting Padding to textfield freeze my screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I am Navigating View from `FirstViewController` to `SecondViewContoller` using `Push`.
In my `SecondViewContoller` I am having a `UITextField` and I have used this code for setting the padding of `UITextField`.

```
   UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 20)];
   textfield.leftView = paddingView;
   textfield.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Now when I navigate, my first view got stuck on `SecondViewContoller`. I am unable to see anything from `SecondViewContoller` or do any action.

Comment: Hi, can you please mention where you have put this code ? i mean in which method ?

Comment: Added this code in viewDidLoad method

Comment: for more clearance, add screenshots of your UI, storyboard.

Comment: I fixed it by creating separate padding views for Both UITextFields. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also set `Padding` using:

```
txtPassword!.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(10, 0, 0);
```